# Access Name attribute of field in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

how can I access name attribute of fields in asp.net,  I have used UniqueID and I was able to get the name of attribute but I have the form splitted in two different asp controls and I am not able to access the fields name attribute using UniqueID on other control.

for exmple..I have first name, last name in one control and credit card details in other control, I am using jquery validation plugins for validation which does the validation based on name attribute of field. I have the validation written in one control where I am using below code to get the name attribute

```
  <%=txtFNameRoom.UniqueID%>
```

this validation works if I am putting the javascript in this control, I am not able to access the name attributes of credit cards fields which are on other control. I cannot break the validation in two parts because we can only initialize the .validate() method once. Anyone has any idea how can I get the name attribute of fields even though they are in different controls.

Comment: what does the HTML output look like?

Comment: output gives me an error saying txtFNameRoom does not exist in current context...it is not able to recognize the <%=txtFNameRoom.UniqueID%> which was in other control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there's a better way, but this should work:

In your other control, expose a property:

```
public string[] FieldsToValidate 
{
    get
    {
        return new[]{ txtCreditCardNumber.UniqueID, txtFNameRoom.UniqueID .. etc };
    }  
}
```

Then, in the first control you can access that property:

```
<% foreach(var id in ControlId.FieldsToValidate) { %>
    // <script... etc
    <%= id %>

<% } %> 
....
<uc1:TestControl ID="ControlId" runat="server" />
```